# Will enums in C# be able to hold undefined values indefinitely?

Tags: c#

Given this enum:

```
enum Numbers 
{
    One = 1, Two, Three
}
```

And then this code:

```
var thousandAndTwo = Numbers.Two + 1000;
Console.WriteLine(thousandAndTwo);
```

Will display `1002` on the console. I know this is expected behavior, but am wondering: can I actually rely on this to always work, and keep working with subsequent versions of C#?

My reason for asking this: I have an enum that indicates the type of a certain kind of message that has a generic structure. Its type indicates what the generic data actually means. All message types used to be known, but now, there is the need for a more dynamic approach, where message types can vary and fall outside of scope of the defined values for the enumeration.

Comment: The code you show does not compile for me. There's no implicit conversion from enum to int, so `Numbers.Two + 1000` does not compile.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, nobody can predict the future C# spec, but why not just specify them yourself? What's the use case for this in the first place?

Comment: I can't see why Microsoft should change the way enums work, especially considering that to do so would break all legacy code.

Comment: @PMF At least in LINQPad, I get that error if I do `Numbers x = 9;`, but not if I do `Number x = Numbers.One + 9`.

Comment: The chance that Microsoft will introduce such a massive breaking change (without providing an option to disable it) is approximately zero.

Comment: You have little to fear from the C# compiler.  Fear the programmer on the other end of the wire instead.  Keeping the enum will be grossly misleading to the reader, you express "the only rule is that there are no rules" by changing the declaration to `int`.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? What about this question makes it "opinion based"? I am apparently unable to properly ask questions about real issues I face, cause no matter how cautiously I proceed, I get downvotes every time. It's really somewhat demotivating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current version of language the Enum may have any value of underlying type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#186-enum-values-and-operations

> The set of values of the enum type is the same as the set of values of the underlying type and is not restricted to the values of the named constants.

I can't predict future, but my opinion is that MS unlikely will heavily change this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we use switch statement to deal with messages

```
switch(num)
{
    case Numbers.One: HandleOne(); break;
    case Numbers.Two: HandleTwo(); break;
    case Numbers.Three: HandleThree(); break;
    default: throw new NotDefinedMessageTypeException();
}
```

If you have some difficulty to use switch in your code, you can also use Enum.IsDefined to test the enum value.

```
if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Numbers), num)))
{
     throw new NotDefinedMessageTypeException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I also use this kind of construct, however, the current issue is that I wish to widen the options of possible enumeration values dynamically. As enums are actually just numbers, this could work; I was wondering if this behavior could be relied on.